# Debugging libgdx/html project in Netbeans

Tags: html, debugging, libgdx, netbeans-8

I've created a sample libgdx/html project in NetBeans 8 and I've followed this guide  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans. When I try to run it right-clicking the HTML project, then Tasks/superDev, NetBeans compiles everything without errors and gives me the link to click. I click the link but the browser says "The web page is not available".
Here are the last log lines from the NetBeans compilation output:

```
 Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
    Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
 soundmanager2-setup.js
 soundmanager2-jsmin.js

 Link succeeded
 Compilation succeeded -- 30,218s
 Compile completed in 31349 ms
 2014-10-15 17:07:19.171:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
 2014-10-15 17:07:19.529:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started                                                        
 SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:9876

 The code server is ready.
 Next, visit: http://localhost:9876/
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. Try uploading the files to Mozilla Thimble or some other fancy code-edit system. That way it will show if it will correctly execute or not.

```html
<a class = "Squirrel Tech">Need more help? Just reply.</a>
```